# Parsing through an arrayref and adding to a new one

Tags: perl

I have $arrayRef that looks like this:

```
[
          {
            'NUM' => '1',
            'QUOTEKEY' => 'DM343'
            'TYPE' => 'DIAMD',
            'COST' => '130'
          },
          {
            'NUM' => '1',
            'QUOTEKEY' => 'DM343'
            'TYPE' => 'ABC',
            'COST' => '150'
          },
          {
            'NUM' => '2',
            'QUOTEKEY' => 'ZX120'
            'TYPE' => 'DIAMD',
            'COST' => '100'
          },
          {
            'NUM' => '2',
            'QUOTEKEY' => 'ZX120'
            'TYPE' => 'ABC',
            'COST' => '200'
          }
]
```

And I am trying to combine it down so it would look something like this:

```
[
          {
            'NUM' => '1',
            'QUOTEKEY' => 'DM343'
            'DIAMD' => '130',
            'ABC' => '150'
          },
          {
            'NUM' => '2',
            'QUOTEKEY' => 'ZX120'
            'DIAMD' => '100',
            'ABC' => '200'
          }
]
```

I am not sure the best way or where to begin to loop through the original array ref to get the desired output. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what process are you using to combine? Simply deduplicating 'num'?  Or doing that and taking the max of `COST`? And is that a typo on the last line where the last ihtng is `ABC => 200`?

Comment: @Sobrique Well Im having trouble starting off with anything that works right. I dont know how to combine them right now.

Comment: @Sobrique its a Data::Dumper dump of my database read. My variable looks like this:  $sth->fetchall_arrayref({});

Comment: Better change your sql query; this is a database job.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "combine". What rules are you trying to implement?

Comment: In the output, shouldn't `COST` be `ABC`?

Comment: @skmrx yes sorry that was a typo

Comment: @melpomene I am trying to put the different values into a single hash ref under the same NUM

Comment: This is starting to smell like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @BluGeni OK, and what should that single hash ref contain, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there is an array of hashes. To access each, you need to dereference - e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $array_ref = [
    {   'NUM'      => '1',
        'QUOTEKEY' => 'DM343',
        'TYPE'     => 'DIAMD',
        'COST'     => '130',
    },
    {   'NUM'      => '1',
        'QUOTEKEY' => 'DM343',
        'TYPE'     => 'ABC',
        'COST'     => '150',
    },
    {   'NUM'      => '2',
        'QUOTEKEY' => 'ZX120',
        'TYPE'     => 'DIAMD',
        'COST'     => '100',
    },
    {   'NUM'      => '2',
        'QUOTEKEY' => 'ZX120',
        'TYPE'     => 'ABC',
        'COST'     => '200',
    }
];

print Dumper \$array_ref;

foreach my $hash_ref (@$array_ref) {
    print Dumper \$hash_ref;
    print $hash_ref ->{'TYPE'}, "\n";
}
```

However as noted in the comments under the question - given your data source is a database, it's inefficent to extract data then post process it - generally it's better to do it upstream.

It looks like what we're trying to do is merge the rows, such that instead of `COST` and `TYPE` per record, they're converted.

Something like this:

```
foreach my $hash_ref (@$array_ref) {
    print Dumper \$hash_ref;
    $type_cost{$hash_ref->{'NUM'}}{$hash_ref->{'QUOTEKEY'}}{$hash_ref->{'TYPE'}} = $hash_ref -> {'COST'};

}

print Dumper \%type_cost;

my $combined; 

foreach my $id ( keys %type_cost ) {
   foreach my $quote ( keys %{$type_cost{$id}} ) {
        push ( @$combined, { NUM => $id, QUOTEKEY => $quote, %{$type_cost{$id}{$quote}}} );
   }
}

print Dumper $combined;
```

This gives us:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'DIAMD' => '130',
            'QUOTEKEY' => 'DM343',
            'NUM' => '1',
            'ABC' => '150'
          },
          {
            'DIAMD' => '100',
            'QUOTEKEY' => 'ZX120',
            'ABC' => '200',
            'NUM' => '2'
          }
        ];
```

As you can see - probably better done within the database.

Comment: I think this is what I needed an really helps me get on the right track, I do agree this would be better done on the database but because of the poor setup of the db it would require a lot of nested selects and would not look pretty. I am also not able to change the database structure.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:

You don't need to quote strings preceeded by the fat comma **=>**

```
my $a = [              
 { NUM => '1', QUOTEKEY => 'DM343', TYPE => 'DIAMD', COST => '130' },              
 { NUM => '1', QUOTEKEY => 'DM343', TYPE => 'ABC', COST => '150' },     
 { NUM => '2', QUOTEKEY => 'ZX120', TYPE => 'DIAMD', COST => '100' },      
 { NUM => '2', QUOTEKEY => 'ZX120', TYPE => 'ABC', COST => '200' },  
];

# Add the following to get the combined output

use Data::Dumper;

my $c;

for ( @$a ){
   $c->{ $_->{ NUM } }{ QUOTEKEY } = $_->{ QUOTEKEY };
   $c->{ $_->{ NUM } }{ $_->{ TYPE } } = $_->{ COST };
}

print Dumper $c;
```

### Output

```
$VAR1 = {
      '2' => {
               'QUOTEKEY' => 'ZX120',
               'DIAMD' => '100',
               'ABC' => '200'
             },
      '1' => {
               'DIAMD' => '130',
               'QUOTEKEY' => 'DM343',
               'ABC' => '150'
             }
    };
```